Is there a way to hide an emacs window only from an external display?
Sometimes when giving a demo or writing code in front of an audience, I like to have my notes displayed in one window as I work in another.  Except--I don't like spoiling the punch line so to speak by broadcasting my notes as well.  I just end up printing them.
It would be nice if there was a way to hide a certain window from the frame when it is rendered on an external display.
Think about the Microsoft Powerpoint presenter view where what is shown to the public is not what the presenter sees.
This maybe a little hard.  Usually I like to mirror my display to the external display because I want to know what the audience is seeing at all times. I am just asking here in case there is an obvious command or a package that does this and I have been sleeping on.

"I like to mirror my display to the external display" -- are you saying that on a mirrored display, a Powerpoint window renders differently on each display? Surely not?! (and if so... that's not mirroring!). You can, of course, trivially have two different Emacs frames displaying the same buffer -- so you can see the buffer(s) your audience sees without it being in the same frame/window.  You wouldn't be mirroring the display with that approach -- but I don't understand how that could work.

You could probably achieve that with another frame and Prot's package beframe - https://github.com/protesilaos/beframe
